# Using JSON to create downloadable link in 3rd column using the values of 2 columns in SharePoint online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am new to JSON. Here is what I am trying to do:

first column name -> firstname and 
second column name -> lastname.

Then in third column I need this to display as a downloadable link -> Randomtext/firstname/lastname.

For example https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/firstname/lastname

I tried below code but doesn't work:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=[$firstname] + ' ' + [$lastname]",
"attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/sites/file.txt' = [$firstname] + ' ' + [$lastname]"
}
}
```

Comment: In order to make it a hyperlink you need to use `a` element. also there was some issue with `href` attribute in your code. I corrected it (check below answer). You said you want the column in `https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/firstname/lastname` format. But, in your code you are doing something else. I don't understand why you are appending firstname and lastname after file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try using your JSON code like below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "txtContent": "=[$FirstName] + ' ' + [$LastName]",
    "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/' + [$FirstName] + '/' + [$LastName]",
        "title": "='https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/' + [$FirstName] + '/' + [$LastName]"
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

On click of link it open new tab with URL:

[image]

Also, note that you need to use [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of your First Name and Last Name columns in JSON code.

**official documentation**:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: I tried but the third column is empty, doesn't display any value. What I noticed is when I am not adding the "attributes" to JSON code, the third column displays the combined values in simple text form. But as soon as i add "attributes" nothing gets displayed.

Comment: This will give you the hyperlink with the format you mentioned: `https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/firstname/lastname`

Comment: Have you tried replacing `elmType` from `div` to `a` ?

Comment: Try using updated code and replace column names in my code with internal name of your columns.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help!!...the code worked perfectly with the changes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with the JSON Below

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "='randomeTxt'+[$firstColumnName]+' '+[$secondColumnName]",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "="='https://www.sagar.sharepoint.com/sites/file.txt' + [$firstColumnName] + ' ' + [$secondColumnName]"
   }
}
```

As I am not quite sure about the link you actually want i simply made some assumption about it.

Comment: It worked..Thank you!! :)

Comment: @sk5991 Glad to hear that. You can mark the reply as answer so other community members will be able to find it easily.